# Why can't certain passwords be entered using ipad bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, passwords, bluetooth, ipad

Using an iPad 2 and a Zagg Folio bluetooth keyboard, I can't type the password to certain WiFi setups which require a guest login via a web page. The access point has no security, but you can't access anything without visiting a web page and entering a password. When that screen is up, and the cursor is in the password field, the keyboard is not responsive. In order to enter the password, I have had to turn the keyboard off, and enter the password using the on-screen keyboard.

I am seeing this on at least two networks. One is a residential Linksys/Cisco, and another is at a hotel.

So, what could be going on here? Is there *anything* a web designer or access point designer could have done (accidentally?) to cause this? Normally, I find the bluetooth keyboard works reliably and interchangeably with the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Okay, here's the source of one such:

Comment: I wasn't able to capture the source before moving out of range of the networks in question. I'm keeping an eye out for this to happen again. I did encounter a situation where, using a bluetooth keyboard with AppleTV, I was unable to logon to Crackle. I finally changed my Crackle password from another computer to have different special characters, and then was able to logon using the keyboard/AppleTV easily. I can only conclude that certain characters were not being passed correctly through this setup. (probably caret or tilde).